# Login Screen Language Still in Dutch Even After Removing

Tags: login-screen, language-support

To be clear I'm not asking about a layout, just the actual text displayed on the login screen. It's remained in Dutch even after applying English system-wide and removing Dutch altogether. Is there anything I can do to change it back to English?

Comment: No, the text on the login screen in completely in Dutch. Not the keyboard layout.

Comment: We don't know what OS & release you're asking about, nor the desktop or DM/greeter you're using. Some greeters have their own settings (ie. the changed settings of a desktop only take effect after you've logged in, thus changes to language need to be made twice, once for the DM & once for the desktop).

Comment: Ok.. Then please edit your question and show us the output of the terminal command `cat /etc/default/locale`